# Permission Denied error in Xcode 10 preventing Build...Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode, xcode10

I'm unable to Build/Archive my project due to an error:

> Permission denied
>   Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

I have tried correcting keychain login as advised by other answers, but it hasn't worked. Please could someone help? Most likely a rookie mistake but means I cannot even simulate my app.

Further details on the error:

```
PhaseScriptExecution Copy\ Pods\ Resources 

/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trials-fseuxkwjlleukxdxyfgdrujhdwuy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/trials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/trials.build/Script-8DEE2FC97BFA0D6E636019C4.sh (in target: trials)
    cd /Users/james/pCloud\ Drive/3.\ NeuroRecovery\ Ltd/4.\ Products/3.\ NIHR\ Trial\ NHS/v1.0\ -\ Initial\ App/1.\ App\ Delivery/3.\ Source\ Code/1.\ iOS/trials
    /bin/sh -c /Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trials-fseuxkwjlleukxdxyfgdrujhdwuy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/trials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/trials.build/Script-8DEE2FC97BFA0D6E636019C4.sh

/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trials-fseuxkwjlleukxdxyfgdrujhdwuy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/trials.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/trials.build/Script-8DEE2FC97BFA0D6E636019C4.sh: line 2: /Users/james/pCloud Drive/3. NeuroRecovery Ltd/4. Products/3. NIHR Trial NHS/v1.0 - Initial App/1. App Delivery/3. Source Code/1. iOS/trials/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-trials/Pods-trials-resources.sh: Permission denied
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Edit 17th Dec: 
thank you @geno-chen & @fantini I have checked & can report the following:

1. Did you install Cocoapods with sudo: Yes.
2. I checked the permissions of the files using ls -lh and had the following: 
   -rw-r--r--   1 james  staff   159B 25 Mar  2015 Podfile
   -rw-r--r--   1 james  staff   1.2K 25 Mar  2015 Podfile.lock
   drwxr-xr-x  11 james  staff   352B 17 Dec 14:03 Pods
   drwxr-xr-x  52 james  staff   1.6K 17 Dec 14:03 trials
   drwxr-xr-x@  5 james  staff   160B 17 Dec 14:03 trials.xcodeproj
   drwxr-xr-x@  5 james  staff   160B 17 Dec 14:03 trials.xcworkspace
   drwxr-xr-x   4 james  staff   128B 17 Dec 14:03 trialsTests
3. I used chmod to modify permissions of the podfiles as below: 
   -rwxr-xr-x   1 james  staff   159B 25 Mar  2015 Podfile
   -rwxr-xr-x   1 james  staff   1.2K 25 Mar  2015 Podfile.lock
   drwxr-xr-x  11 james  staff   352B 17 Dec 14:03 Pods
   drwxr-xr-x  52 james  staff   1.6K 17 Dec 14:03 trials
   drwxr-xr-x@  5 james  staff   160B 17 Dec 14:03 trials.xcodeproj
   drwxr-xr-x@  5 james  staff   160B 17 Dec 14:03 trials.xcworkspace
   drwxr-xr-x   4 james  staff   128B 17 Dec 14:03 trialsTests

I then Cleaned my Build Folder, restarted but still have the same error.

Comment: It said "permission denied", then what is its permission? Maybe what you need is a `chmod +x`?

Comment: Did you install Cocoapods with `sudo` did you run the install also with `sudo`? I'm thinking that your problem could be related with that, your user `james` doesn't have the permission to run that script (the one that was generated by Cocoapods). Go to the script location and list your files and permissions using `ls -lh`, add that to the question pls.

Comment: added info above - thanks!

Answer (score 59):

I fixed the permission problem by running the following command.

```
chmod +x "Path to .sh"
```

Please replace `ProjectName` with your project name and `username` with your username

```
chmod +x /Users/username/Documents/ProjectName/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-ProjectName/Pods-ProjectName-frameworks.sh
```

You can get the path from your xcode project as explained by step 1 to 3

[image]

Comment: How to give this permission permenently. In my case permission denied issues is coming each time when a new version of app is building. So I have to execute this command on every new build

Comment: This works!
I suppose we need to re-grant the "executable" permission to the script if the pod is brought along with the project from the internet.
By the way, we can use `ls -l "scriptPath"` to check if the permission is granted successfully.

Answer (score 33):

I've tried @Sawsan method but get no luck even the file is already executable.

Here is the step how I solve it:

1.delete Podfile.lock

2.delete Pods directory

3.delete .xcworkspace file

4.Pod install again

that's it.

give it a try!

Comment: Simple and perfect. Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect solution! Should be marked this as the answer

Answer (score 18):

I have to own a trial for this solution and I got a proper result.

Follow the step:

1) Open Terminal and set a project path

**"pod deintegrate"** command executes

2) Then after **"pod install"** command executes.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I solved by deleting the **Pods** folder that was committed to the repo.